# XML-Multi-Parsing in C#

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I need to parse a Xml-structure like this in C#:

```
<Root>
  <respcondition continue="Yes">
    <conditionvar>
      <varequal respident="gap_0">auswahl1</varequal>
    </conditionvar>
    <setvar action="Add">1</setvar>
    <displayfeedback linkrefid="0_Response_0" feedbacktype="Response"/>
  </respcondition>
  <respcondition continue="Yes">
    <conditionvar>
      <varequal respident="gap_0">auswahl2</varequal>
    </conditionvar>
    <setvar action="Add">2</setvar>
    <displayfeedback linkrefid="0_Response_1" feedbacktype="Response"/>
  </respcondition>
</Root>
```

I want to parse it like the following: I know which "gap_x" have multiple entries so I want to compare it with varequal attribute "respident" and if it matches, it should be stored in a string list. If the gap appears at first time, there should be a new list entry for it, if it appears second(or more)-time it should be added to the existing list entry to the corresponding "gap_x".

I have created a list earlier with following content:
multigaps[0]="gap_0"
multigaps[1]="gap_1"

In the end the list should look like this:
list[0]=auswahl1;auswahl2      (all values with gap_0 in respident)///
list[1]=antwort1;antwort2      (all values with gap_1 in respident)

There can be more than 2 entries for it, this is only an example.

In addition i need to parse the corresponding
`<setvar action="Add">x</setvar>`
to a second list which stores this values in same structure like this:

points[0]=1;2      (belongs to gap_0)///
points[1]=3;4      (belongs to gap_1)

Comment: And what exactly is your question? Did you already try to parse the XML with `XDocument` or `XmlDocument`?

Comment: Yes I know how to parse a XML file I used XMLTextReader, my problem is that there are multiple entries for each gap_x and the corresponding value like "antwort1" "antwort2" need to be stored together in 1 string like "antwort1;antwort2" but only the ones that belongs to the gap_x. There can be more than 2 entries for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using xml linq I put results into a dictionary parsing all the properties in the xml

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication97
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<Respcondition> responses = doc.Descendants("respcondition").Select(x => new Respcondition()
            {
                _continue = (string)x.Attribute("continue"),
                varequal = (string)x.Descendants("varequal").FirstOrDefault(),
                respident = (string)x.Descendants("varequal").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("respident"),
                setvar = (string)x.Element("setvar"),
                action = (string)x.Element("setvar").Attribute("action"),
                linkrefid = (string)x.Element("displayfeedback").Attribute("linkrefid"),
                feedbacktype = (string)x.Element("displayfeedback").Attribute("feedbacktype")
            }).ToList();

            Dictionary<string, List<Respcondition>> dict = responses.GroupBy(x => x.respident, y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());

        }
    }
    public class Respcondition
    {
        public string _continue { get; set; }
        public string varequal { get; set; }
        public string respident { get; set; }
        public string setvar { get; set; }
        public string action { get; set; }
        public string linkrefid { get; set; }
        public string feedbacktype { get; set; }
    }


}

 //<respcondition continue="Yes">
 //   <conditionvar>
 //     <varequal respident="gap_0">auswahl1</varequal>
 //   </conditionvar>
 //   <setvar action="Add">1</setvar>
 //   <displayfeedback linkrefid="0_Response_0" feedbacktype="Response"/>
 // </respcondition>
```

Comment: it seems to work like expected but only if i add <Root>   </Root> around this xml part. But the XML i want to parse has much more values in it so i need to extract the respcondition part from a greater XML and then add <Root> around it. How to do this? I can give you an example of a whole XML file.

Comment: I need to parse this whole file i posted in my answer and need only the parts I mentioned before. All other content is not needed for this. Your solution works in this part of the file but not with the whole xml file

Comment: There a lots of methods in Net to parse xml.  The best depends if you have a schema, the size of the xml, the amount of data you need to parse, and the format of the output.  I only parsed the section of code you posted.  You can modify code to handle the rest of the file.

Comment: I add root using string methods.   string results = "<Root>" + xml + "</Root>";

Answer (score 0):

````
<!DOCTYPE questestinterop SYSTEM "ims_qtiasiv1p2p1.dtd">

<!--Generated by ILIAS XmlWriter-->

<questestinterop>


<item title="titel" maxattempts="0" ident="il_0_qst_152800">

<qticomment>beschreibung</qticomment>

<duration>P0Y0M0DT0H1M0S</duration>


<itemmetadata>


<qtimetadata>


<qtimetadatafield>

<fieldlabel>ILIAS_VERSION</fieldlabel>

<fieldentry>5.3.8 2018-08-29</fieldentry>

</qtimetadatafield>


<qtimetadatafield>

<fieldlabel>QUESTIONTYPE</fieldlabel>

<fieldentry>CLOZE QUESTION</fieldentry>

</qtimetadatafield>


<qtimetadatafield>

<fieldlabel>AUTHOR</fieldlabel>

<fieldentry>Patrick Maik Mächler</fieldentry>

</qtimetadatafield>


<qtimetadatafield>

<fieldlabel>additional_cont_edit_mode</fieldlabel>

<fieldentry>default</fieldentry>

</qtimetadatafield>


<qtimetadatafield>

<fieldlabel>externalId</fieldlabel>

<fieldentry>5c3f83ce4b6880.97213190</fieldentry>

</qtimetadatafield>


<qtimetadatafield>

<fieldlabel>textgaprating</fieldlabel>

<fieldentry>ci</fieldentry>

</qtimetadatafield>


<qtimetadatafield>

<fieldlabel>fixedTextLength</fieldlabel>

<fieldentry>1</fieldentry>

</qtimetadatafield>


<qtimetadatafield>

<fieldlabel>identicalScoring</fieldlabel>

<fieldentry>1</fieldentry>

</qtimetadatafield>


<qtimetadatafield>

<fieldlabel>combinations</fieldlabel>

<fieldentry>W10=</fieldentry>

</qtimetadatafield>

</qtimetadata>

</itemmetadata>


<presentation label="titel">


<flow>


<material>

<mattext texttype="text/xhtml"><p>text1</p> <div id="OKAYFREEDOM_INJECTED" style="display: none;"></div></mattext>

</material>


<material>

<mattext texttype="text/xhtml"><p></p> <p>text2</p> <p></p> <p>auswahllücke</mattext>

</material>


<response_str ident="gap_0" rcardinality="Single">


<render_choice shuffle="No">


<response_label ident="0">


<material>

<mattext>auswahl1</mattext>

</material>

</response_label>


<response_label ident="1">


<material>

<mattext>auswahl2</mattext>

</material>

</response_label>

</render_choice>

</response_str>


<material>

<mattext texttype="text/plain">textlücke</mattext>

</material>


<response_str ident="gap_1" rcardinality="Single">

<render_fib maxchars="2" columns="8" prompt="Box" fibtype="String"/>

</response_str>


<material>

<mattext texttype="text/plain">numlücke</mattext>

</material>


<response_num ident="gap_2" rcardinality="Single" numtype="Decimal">

<render_fib maxchars="3" columns="2" prompt="Box" fibtype="Decimal" maxnumber="100" minnumber="1"/>

</response_num>


<material>

<mattext texttype="text/xhtml"></p> <p></p> <div></div> <p></p> <div></div> <div></div></mattext>

</material>

</flow>

</presentation>


<resprocessing>


<outcomes>

<decvar/>

</outcomes>


<respcondition continue="Yes">


<conditionvar>

<varequal respident="gap_0">auswahl1</varequal>

</conditionvar>

<setvar action="Add">1</setvar>

<displayfeedback linkrefid="0_Response_0" feedbacktype="Response"/>

</respcondition>


<respcondition continue="Yes">


<conditionvar>

<varequal respident="gap_0">auswahl2</varequal>

</conditionvar>

<setvar action="Add">2</setvar>

<displayfeedback linkrefid="0_Response_1" feedbacktype="Response"/>

</respcondition>


<respcondition continue="Yes">


<conditionvar>

<varequal respident="gap_1">antwort1</varequal>

</conditionvar>

<setvar action="Add">3</setvar>

<displayfeedback linkrefid="1_Response_0" feedbacktype="Response"/>

</respcondition>


<respcondition continue="Yes">


<conditionvar>

<varequal respident="gap_1">antwort2</varequal>

</conditionvar>

<setvar action="Add">4</setvar>

<displayfeedback linkrefid="1_Response_1" feedbacktype="Response"/>

</respcondition>


<respcondition continue="Yes">


<conditionvar>

<varequal respident="gap_2">99</varequal>

</conditionvar>

<setvar action="Add">5</setvar>

<displayfeedback linkrefid="2_Response_0" feedbacktype="Response"/>

</respcondition>


<respcondition continue="Yes">


<conditionvar>

<varequal respident="gap_0">auswahl2</varequal>


<and>

<varequal respident="gap_1">antwort2</varequal>

</and>


<and>

<varequal respident="gap_2">99</varequal>

</and>

</conditionvar>

<displayfeedback linkrefid="response_allcorrect" feedbacktype="Response"/>

</respcondition>


<respcondition continue="Yes">


<conditionvar>


<not>

<varequal respident="gap_0">auswahl2</varequal>


<and>

<varequal respident="gap_1">antwort2</varequal>

</and>


<and>

<varequal respident="gap_2">99</varequal>

</and>

</not>

</conditionvar>

<displayfeedback linkrefid="response_onenotcorrect" feedbacktype="Response"/>

</respcondition>

</resprocessing>


<itemfeedback ident="0" view="All">


<flow_mat>


<material>

<mattext texttype="text/xhtml"><p></p> <div id="OKAYFREEDOM_INJECTED" style="display: none;"></div></mattext>

</material>

</flow_mat>

</itemfeedback>


<itemfeedback ident="1" view="All">


<flow_mat>


<material>

<mattext texttype="text/xhtml"><p></p> <div id="OKAYFREEDOM_INJECTED" style="display: none;"></div></mattext>

</material>

</flow_mat>

</itemfeedback>


<itemfeedback ident="2" view="All">


<flow_mat>


<material>

<mattext texttype="text/xhtml"><p></p> <div id="OKAYFREEDOM_INJECTED" style="display: none;"></div></mattext>

</material>

</flow_mat>

</itemfeedback>


<itemfeedback ident="response_allcorrect" view="All">


<flow_mat>


<material>

<mattext texttype="text/xhtml"><p></p> <div id="OKAYFREEDOM_INJECTED" style="display: none;"></div></mattext>

</material>

</flow_mat>

</itemfeedback>


<itemfeedback ident="response_onenotcorrect" view="All">


<flow_mat>


<material>

<mattext texttype="text/xhtml"><p>respnotcorrect</p> <div id="OKAYFREEDOM_INJECTED" style="display: none;"></div></mattext>

</material>

</flow_mat>

</itemfeedback>

</item>

</questestinterop>```

I need to parse this whole file and need only the parts I mentioned before. All other content is not needed for this.
````